# Correct way to get output from ExecutorCompletionService

Tags: java, executorservice

I'm using ExecutorCompletionService to get the result of the jobs as soon as it completes its execution. Pseudocode is like this-

```
Instantiate FixedThreadPool executor, exec
Instantiate ExecutorCompletionService, completionService
for(taskList) {
   completionService.submit(someTask)
}
exec.shutDown();
whie(!exec.isShutdown()) { //Line 1
   Task t = completionService.take(); //Line 2
}
```

As we know, `shutdown()` waits for the completion of all the submitted tasks , so as long as there is a task in progress while condition on Line1 returns true and code goes inside the loop to take the completed task from the queue and waits if necessary.
Now, I've observed a problem with the above code in which control gets blocked on line2 even if there are no more tasks in progress, all tasks have been completed.
I think it's because when the last task is completed and added to the completion queue, `ThreadPoolExecutor` resumes the shutdown process as there are no more pending submitted tasks. But while it was still shutting down, next iteration takes place and `isShutdown()` returns false so it goes inside the loop and gets blocked by the `take()` call even though there are no more tasks. So maybe it's the time between last `take` call and pool shutting down properly. Am I thinking in the right direction?
So I was thinking if this is the right way to use and get the result from completionservice?
To fix this, I can replace the `while` on line1 with `for(taskList)` in order to avoid `isShutdown` call.
There's another thing, is it the best practice to shutdown the executor and then get the result from completionservice or first collect the result and shutdown the execturo in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ***isTerminated()*** instead of isShutoown(). But the best choice will be to use ***awaitTermination()*** method instead of creating this loop.